# Export multiple tables to one Excel sheet using SSIS

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I am trying to show data in Excel from multiple blocks of sql queries.

There is a stored procedure which give results in the form of multiple tables after execution.

I have to show these tables as they are in a tab in Excel. All tables may have different columns names.

#### Example

if the first table's data starts at cell `A1` and ends at `A4` then, after inserting a couple of blank rows, the second table's data must start from cell `A7` or `A8`, and all should be in same excel tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :
[link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e84dee4f-8c64-46c0-9727-d36517b85d87/how-to-export-multiple-database-tables-in-one-excel-sheet-using-ssis-2008-r2?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

If you want to use benefits of SSIS and Excel destionation connection manager you have to write a query that gives you this result set. Then you can save this data into one excel sheet.